# Android - No Launcher activity found

Tags: android

When I launch my app with Eclipse, I get this error :

```
No Launcher activity found!
launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

However, the `AndroidManifest` seems correct :

```
<application
    android:name="com.myapp.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/name"
    android:theme="@style/myTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.OpeningActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/myxml" />
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.myapp.MyBootReceiver" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
             <action android:name="com.parrot.intent.action.LAUNCH_NAP_APP" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
</application>
```

I can't see anything worst in this code.
Note that with AndroidStudio, this error not appears. So... is Eclipse the problem ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at the related questions. *One* of those must surely apply.

Comment: I guess it's because of `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />`

Comment: Thank you @Zhuinden ;) but why this line causes this problem?

Comment: Why Eclipse? Android Studio is much better!

Comment: But Android Studio is still beta.